# Using jq to show 2nd array for all elements in the first array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to use jq to take 2 arrays and for each element in the first array, show the entire second array.  The input json would look like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "countries": ["GB", "JE"],
      "currencies": ["GBP", "EUR"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The output json should look like:

```
{
  "GB": ["GBP", "EUR"],
  "JE": ["GBP", "EUR"]
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: for your consideration, there's an _alternative_ solution for the JSON manipulation in your ask, based on a unix `walk-path` utility `jtc`: `<input.json jtc -w'<countries>l[:]<C>v[-2][currencies]' -T'{"{C}": {{}} }' -jjll`. Let me know If you're interested - I can elaborate on the tool usage in a separate answer. (PS. I'm a developer of the tool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate objects for each country, and merge them at the end.

```
.data[] | [
  { (.countries[]): .currencies }
] | add
```

Or use this alternative approach with `reduce`:

```
.data[] | reduce { (.countries[]): .currencies } as $f ({}; . + $f)
```